# How to run the code using two OpenCV versions python at the same time?

Tags: python, opencv

Two versions are installed on my computer, OpenCV 3.3.1  is working with ROS library ([kinetic](http://wiki.ros.org/opencv3)) and OpenCV 4.2 has some advantage compared to 3.3.1. So, I'd like to use them both.

simple code:

```
import cv2
print (cv2.__version__)

import sys
ros_path2 = '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages'
ros_path3 = '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages'
if  ros_path2 and ros_path3 in sys.path:
    sys.path.remove(ros_path2)
    sys.path.remove(ros_path3)
import cv2
print (cv2.__version__)
```

The output is:

```
3.3.1

3.3.1
```

if I comment out two first lines

```
# import cv2
# print (cv2.__version__)

import sys
ros_path2 = '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages'
ros_path3 = '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages'
if  ros_path2 and ros_path3 in sys.path:
    sys.path.remove(ros_path2)
    sys.path.remove(ros_path3)
import cv2
print (cv2.__version__)
```

The output becames:

```
4.2.0
```

My goal from this action is to use some advantage OpenCV 4.2 for example: `from cv2.xfeatures2d import matchGMS`

More explanations:

if I added last line as:

```
import cv2
print (cv2.__version__)

import sys
ros_path2 = '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages'
ros_path3 = '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages'
if  ros_path2 and ros_path3 in sys.path:
    sys.path.remove(ros_path2)
    sys.path.remove(ros_path3)
import cv2
from cv2.xfeatures2d import matchGMS
print (cv2.__version__)
```

The output is:

```
3.3.1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/redhwan/learn2.py", line 11, in <module>
    from cv2.xfeatures2d import matchGMS
ImportError: cannot import name matchGMS
```

if I comment out two first lines again:

```
# import cv2
# print (cv2.__version__)

import sys
ros_path2 = '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages'
ros_path3 = '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages'
if  ros_path2 and ros_path3 in sys.path:
    sys.path.remove(ros_path2)
    sys.path.remove(ros_path3)
import cv2
from cv2.xfeatures2d import matchGMS
print (cv2.__version__)
```

It is working fine, the output is:

```
4.2.0
```

Sorry, for long explanation

Any help,thank you in advance.

Comment: basic python mistake. the expression `ros_path2 and ros_path3 in sys.path` **does not mean** "if either of those is in sys.path". it means `bool(ros_path2) and (ros_path3 in sys.path)` which is always true because `ros_path2` is non-empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can use them both because It was not designed it to be that way. I am sorry If I couldn't answer as you might have expected. I hope you work your way around this to avoid this kind of problem. :)